# How to access a private objective C variable in Swift View Controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I've got next to no knowledge about Objective-C. I'm working with an Obj-C framework for an AVCaptureSession. I need to have access to the AVCaptureVideoDataOutput of the camera's session.

In the .m file the session is initialized and set up.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureSession *session;
```

I cannot move the property from the .m to .h file because the .m file needs it for all of the functions to set it up.

I also tried making them readwrite / readonly in the .m and .h respectively to avoid a redeclaration issue, but then when I call on the camera.session after I'm starting the camera up, "session" returns nil and the app crashes.

I don't know if there would be any problem just moving all of the code into the .h file so it's all publicly accessable?

How can I access the session property from a .m file in my View Controller?

Comment: You can move the property from the .m to the .h to change it from private to public. Why don't you think you can? Did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the property to the `.h`. exposes it publicly and also makes it available to the `.m` because the `.m` file by default imports the `.h`. 
Example:

```
// CameraViewController.h
@interface CameraViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureSession *session;
@end 

// CameraViewController.m
#import "CameraViewController.h" // <- notice the import, `session` is accessible internally.
```

As for the `session` property being nil it may be because you have not initialized it with a value yet. In your `init` you may want to initialize `session` with `[[AVCaptureSession alloc] init]`

Note: to avoid potential problems with unintended mutability I recommend asking your self if you can make publicly exposed properties read only i.e.

`@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) AVCaptureSession *session;`

Answer (score 1):

If you move it to the .h the .m has access to it as well. You can even make it readonly in the header and readwrite in the m

So do either:

.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureSession *session;
```

Or:

.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) AVCaptureSession *session;
```

.m:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) AVCaptureSession *session;
```